# Returning data calling function from invoke-command with parameters

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, invoke-command

Apologize for the length..
Trying to modify a script that currently uses robocopy to report a folder path's size, child folder count, and size.  This script currently takes about 24 hrs to run as it goes one by one to each folder.  I'm trying to implement invoke-command to set-up jobs so that it will run at least 10 instances of robocopy in the hopes if drastically reducing run time.

I've tried multiple variances given multiple resources to set parameters, call a function and get the results back with no success.
with current code (below) getting error;

Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
ERROR: +         Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { param ($item,$Filter,$params) $ ...
ERROR: +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

```
    Function ListFolder ($Folder, $FilterSet, $Roboparam)
    {
        write-host $Folder
        Try
        {
            $Folder = (Resolve-Path -LiteralPath $Folder -ErrorAction Stop).ProviderPath
            If (-Not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $Folder -Type Container -ErrorAction Stop))
            {Write-Warning ("{0} is not a directory and will be skipped" -f $Folder)
                Return
            }

            $Script = robocopy $Folder NULL $FilterSet $FRoboparam
            $exit_code = $LASTEXITCODE

            16, 8, 4, 2, 1 | % {
                Switch ($exit_code -band $_)
                {
                    16  { $exit_reason = "Usage error or insufficient access privileges" }
                    8   { $exit_reason = "Retry limit exceeded" }
                    4   { $exit_reason = "Some Mismatched files or directories were detected" }
                    2   { $exit_reason = "Some Extra files or directories were detected. No files were copied" }
                    1   { $exit_reason = " " }
                }
            }
            If ($exit_code -eq 0)
            {$exit_reason = 'No Change'}

            If ($Script[-6] -match $dirPattern)
            {$Dir = $matches.Dir}
            Else
            {$Dir = 0}

            If ($Script[-5] -match $countPattern)
            {$Count = $matches.Count}
            Else
            {$Count = 0}

            If ($Count -gt 0)
            {If ($Script[-4] -match $sizePattern)
                {$FSize = $matches.Size}}
            Else
            {$FSize = 0}

            $Script:TotSize += $FSize
            $Script:Report += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                'Folder Name' = $Folder
                Files         = "{0:N0}" -f [int]$Count
                Folders       = "{0:N0}" -f [int]$Dir
                Size          = "{0:N0}" -f [long]$FSize
                Comment       = $exit_reason}

            Clear-Variable -Name Dir
            Clear-Variable -Name Count
            Clear-Variable -Name FSize
            If ($exit_reason) { Clear-Variable -Name exit_reason }}
        Catch
        {$Script:Report += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                'Folder Name' = $Folder
                Files         = "{0:N0}" -f [int]$Count
                Folders       = "{0:N0}" -f [int]$Dir
                Size          = [long]$FSize
                Comment       = [string]$_.Exception.Message}
            Continue
        }

        Return #$Script
    }
    }

$params = New-Object System.Collections.Arraylist
$params.AddRange(@("/L","/S","/NJH","/BYTES","/FP","/NFL","/NC","/NDL","/TS","/XJ","/R:0","/W:0"))
$dirPattern = "^\s{4}Dirs\s:\s+(?<Dir>\d+).*"
$countPattern = "^\s{3}Files\s:\s+(?<Count>\d+).*"
$sizePattern = "^\s{3}Bytes\s:\s+(?<Size>\d+(?:\.?\d+)).*"

If ($PSBoundParameters['Force']) {$FileDate = 10}

If ($FileDate -lt 6){Exit}
Else
{$Paths = Get-Content $InputFile
    ForEach ($item in $Paths)
    {
        $MaxThreads = 10
        While (@(Get-Job | where { $_.State -eq "Running" }).Count -ge $MaxThreads)
            {
            Write-Host "Waiting for open thread...($MaxThreads Maximum)"
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
            }
        Invoke-Command -Computer . -ScriptBlock { param ($item,$Filter,$params) ${function:ListFolder} } -ArgumentList $item, $Filter, $params -AsJob
    }
}
```

When all said and done I have a collection of $Report to show folder name, count of files, count of folders, size in bytes, and comments tho show any errors to Excel

```
$Report | Sort-Object {[long]$_.Size} -descending | Select 'Folder Name', Files, Folders, Size, Comment | Export-Csv -Path $ReportPath\$(Get-Date -uformat "%Y_%m_%d")-FileSizes.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Can you use a script or a scriptblock instead of `${function:ListFolder}`?  `$filter` is unset.

Comment: Also argumentlist has a hard time with arrays.  `(,$params)`